# Is 3-way switching circuitry compatible with smart ceiling fans?

Tags: ceiling-fan, smart-switch, smart-home

I'm gathering from research that generally smart fan control switches are single pole only. We have wiring for a 3-way switched  fan/light fixture.

1. Do 3-way smart fan switches exist?
2. Do intrinsically smart fan/light fixtures with 3-way switches included exist?

If neither 1 nor 2 are true, do we have other options besides just converting the wiring to 1 way?

Comment: What do you have right now? A set of 3-way switches for fan and a set of 3-way switches for light? A set of 3-way switches that turns everything on/off and you use pull-strings to adjust speed and light? Something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never say never, but:  FWIW, I have never seen a 3-way smart fan switch or smart fan with 3-way switches.
Yes, you have another option:  use a smart fan controller like ["Universal Smart Wi-Fi 4-Speed Ceiling Fan Remote Works with Google Assistant, SmartThings, and Alexa"](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Universal-Smart-Wi-Fi-4-Speed-Ceiling-Fan-Remote-Works-with-Google-Assistant-SmartThings-and-Alexa-99434/311264804) (not an endorsement).  Use any of the many devices compatible with those home tech systems to control the fan from anywhere.

Comment: Ohhh so potentially get a dumb fan and dumb three way switches, and a smart _remote_, right?

Comment: No.  If you did that, the switches would turn off power to the fan, rendering it unable to respond to the smart remote and any other smart controllers.  You would need to bypass the two 3-way switches and install the receiver part of the smart switch inside the fan housing.  You can always run it from the remote.  Read the instructions to set it up  to run from an app on phone (s) or integrate with the specified smart home systems.  If you're not sure of your power wiring skills, you should hire an electrician.

Comment: Oh, I see how this works now. Understood!

Answer (score 1):

You say "3-way" but what you actually want is control of the fan/light in two places.  You're not married to the idea of using dumb, plain "3-way" switches in the second location.

Generally with smart switches, when you're dealing with anything more than a plain on/off switch, the primary location is handled by a smart-switch master, and then secondary locations are handled by a smart switch remote. They don't reuse the legacy on/off switches, because they have more to do than just on/off, and they want to provide the full suite of controls at each location.

Some will provide some degree of support for it, but obviously the remote being a simple on/off switch will not give access to all abilities.

Generally the master switch needs to be as close as possible to the lamp/fan, so if the 3-way arrangement is power -> switch 1 -> switch 2 -> fan, the master goes in the switch 2 location, and you don't get a choice to that.